# Python: list of strings, change color of character if found (using xlsxwriter)

Tags: python, colors, xlsxwriter

I have several lists I am writing to different columns/rows of an excel spreadsheet using xlsxwriter in python 2.7. For one list of strings (DNA sequences), I want to find certain characters in the string ('a','t','c','g'), change their individual colors, and then write the complete list of strings (multicolored strings, per character) to one column in the spreadsheet.

So far the code I have writen is:

```
row = 1
col = 1
for i in (seqs):
    worksheet.write(row,1,i,green)
    for char in i:
        if i.__contains__("A") or i.__contains__("T") :
            worksheet.write(row,1,i[char],red)
row += 1
```

Where seqs is my list of sequences.  I want A/T to be red, and G/C to be green and the full sequence written to the spreadsheet. I'm not getting any errors, but I either write the entire sequence per row in excel in green, or one character per row in red.  Is there any way to do this/get this code to work?

Comment: not wanting to be fussy, but could you correct your indentation a bit?  it looks kinda funky around the two for loops.  which makes it hard to see what is going regarding your issue.

Comment: Check out https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_rich_string.  write_rich_string looks like it would do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with XlsxWriter's [`write_rich_string()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string) method.

Here is a small working example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('sequences.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
green = workbook.add_format({'color': 'green'})

sequences = [
    'ACAAGATG',
    'CCATTGTC',
    'CCCCGGCC',
    'CCTGCTGC',
    'GCTGCTCT',
    'CGGGGCCA',
    'GGCCACCG',
]

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

for row_num, sequence in enumerate(sequences):

    format_pairs = []

    # Get each DNA base character from the sequence.
    for base in sequence.upper():

        # Prefix each base with a format.
        if base == 'A' or base == 'T':
            format_pairs.extend((red, base))

        elif base == 'G' or base == 'C':
            format_pairs.extend((green, base))

        else:
            # Non base characters are unformatted.
            format_pairs.append(base)

    worksheet.write_rich_string(row_num, 0, *format_pairs)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Works in my code perfectly. Thank @jmcnamara

Comment: Is there some default option for row_num that causes it to index from 0?  For example if I want to start populating the spreadsheet with colored sequences from row 10 rather than row 0?  I have tried assigning a         worksheet.set_row('10:len(list)') and setting the row_num = 10 prior to, but it always seems to index by 0.

Comment: I tried again, initiating between for loops and this seems to work just fine.